# dataframe subsetting using vector

Tags: r, vector, using, subset

I have a Data Frame

```
head(readDF1)

          Date sulfate nitrate   ID
279 2003-10-06    7.21   0.651    1
285 2003-10-12    5.99   0.428   10
291 2003-10-18    4.68   1.040  100
297 2003-10-24    3.47   0.363  200
303 2003-10-30    2.42   0.507  300
315 2003-11-11    1.43   0.474  332
```

If I'm subsetting using the below code it is working correct

```
readDF1[readDF1$ID==331]
```

but If I'm using

```
readDF1[readDF1$ID==1:300]
```

this is not working, I want to subset a Dataframe wihch has the values of the column ID from 1 to 300 (Asssume that ID contains values from 1 to 1000 and they are multiple)

Comment: If you want `1:300` why did you write `1:331`?

Comment: Even if I use 1:300 it's not working.

Comment: I think there has to be some other way to subset dataframe if I have to subset multiple values(Vector of values)

Comment: It's `%in%`.  See arvi1000's answer for the `ID` column.  Are you looking for the rows?  If so, it's `readDF1[readDF1$ID %in% 1:300,]`

Comment: the following code worked readDF1$ID[readDF1$ID %in% 1:331]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

== is the wrong operator here. You aren't asking 'which ID is equal to the sequence 1:331'.
You want %in% (i.e. which ID values can be found in 1:331

```
readDF1$ID[readDF1$ID %in% 1:331]
```

Comment: Just a word of advice, this answer will probably end up in the "low-quality answer" queue unless you add a few words of explanation

Comment: And sure enough, here it is, in "Review Low Quality Posts". Looks like an attempt to answer to me.

Comment: Okay thanks. I was matching the level of effort I perceived in the question, but obv it's good practice to be more gracious...